# How to re-Import the WordPress XML file after editing?

Tags: import, xml

I have exported all my content to WordPress XML file via WordPress>Tools>Export as I needed to edit 300 posts at a time. Now, my concern is how to re import the file to override the default one? 
By re-importing the file via WordPress Tools it does only import new posts, so it's not adapted to that particular case without breaking my site/database. I need to find a way to re import the file.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered just doing it in a different way? What is your issue with editing in first place?

Comment: Do you mean editing 200 to 300 posts html source code on WordPress dashboard by going to every single post?

Comment: What are you trying to edit in first place?

Comment: I mean there are tools for changing data in database, etc. Clearly import/export approach is problematic for your use case, but it's hard to say what would work better without understanding of what your use case is precisely.

Comment: What I need to edit is the source Html code of each post. For example removing the 'text-align: justify' inside the blockquote, correcting some duplicate tags, removing old shortcodes, editing some characters from uppercase to small caps, etc...

Answer (score 1):

What do you need to edit and why can't you edit in the WP editor?

Can you use [Search RegEx](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/)? It's a plugin to search and replace with grep and regular expressions through content.

If you need to develop a regex search string to find certain content, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex

Comment: I'm changing of template and need to edit the source code for each post to match with the new template.

Comment: That plugin will edit all posts at once, with grep, if needed.

Comment: I need to remove text align justify inside all the blockquote + every tag like <i> or <em> and remove the closing tags </p>. It's not just a search/replace process, I'm not sure this plugin will do the trick. Using Notepad++ you can do the job in one click for all the template.

Comment: Also, need to find a way to remove extra/redundant formatting tags

Comment: Yes, it will. You can do all that with grep. But grep is not specific to WordPress. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex

Comment: Certain themes, more like frameworks (for example Pro theme and X theme) do not let you edit the content directly. You must go through their tools for every edit, which includes layout/css. It would be nearly impossible to copy over every change. There is great power in these tools, but even the content is not directly editable, which creates a great problem for versioning, editing, and exporting/importing between dev and live sites. Too bad the Import tool does not ASK "replace" or "skip", when it runs across existing pages.  I've done DB `INSERT ... on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE..` queries, but :(

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to do this, then you'll have to delete the existing posts completely - ie 'Bin' them, and then Empty the bin/trash. You'll then be able to import the WXR file via Tools | Import.

Comment: Yes, Anu makes an important point that needs highlighting: in my experience, if you do not empty (those posts from) the trash, WP sees those posts as still existing, and thus will not import them.